# Loading custom validation yml in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.1

I'm using Symfony3 (together with SonataAdminBundle) and I'm in need of creating some validation files. Since I have several entities and I'd like to split the validation yml files into one per entity, I would like to use a dependency injection loader to load those files. Now, the questions that I have are these:

1. If I create a custom loader for my validation files, do I need to manually load my services.yml and routing.yml as well?
2. Is there any obvious issue with my code that would cause the following error?

> InvalidArgumentException in YamlFileLoader.php line 404:  There is no
>   extension able to load the configuration for
>   "UserAdminBundle\Entity\User" (in
>   *****src/UserAdminBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/validation/validation.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "UserAdminBundle\Entity\User", found none

My file:

```
UserAdminBundle\Entity\User:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [email]
            message: 'This user already exists'
UserAdminBundle\Entity\TaxToReseller:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [resellerId, taxId]
            message: 'Reseller already has this tax'
UserAdminBundle\Entity\Tax:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity:
            fields: [ name, value ]
            message: 'This tax already exists'
```

My load method:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{

    $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
        $container,
        new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
    );

    //$loader->load('validation/validation.yml');
    $loader->load('validation/agent_validation.yml');
    $loader->load('validation/call_centre_validation.yml');
    $loader->load('validation/reseller_header_validation.yml');
    $loader->load('validation/reseller_validation.yml');
    $loader->load('validation/tax_validation.yml');

}
```

I could use some ideas as to why it can't find things!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Validation files in `Resources/config/validation` are loaded by default. There's no need to edit the load method.

Comment: thanks, although I would still like to know how to do that properly

Comment: @AndreiDascalu it's proper enough for validation purposes. If you, however, intend to load other configuration than just validation, you should take a look at these parts of documentation:
[How to Create Friendly Configuration for a Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html)
[Defining and Processing Configuration Values](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Symfomy provides a build-in way for mapping constraints for custom entities, models... with external yaml files. This can be accomplished via configuration (https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html):

```
# packages/validation.yaml
framework:
    validation:
        mapping:
            paths:
              - '.../user-model.yaml'
              - '.../cart-model.yaml'
```

You can also load yaml files on-the-fly when building a form type getting a right separation of concerns.
Here you are a sample code I used in production:

```
# Example validation.yaml file  
YourNamespace\YourModel:
properties:
    name:
        -   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank:
                message: 'Full name required'
        -   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length:
                min: 7
    email:
        -   Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank:
                message: 'E-mail required'


public function add(FormBuilderInterface $builder, string $yamlFilePath, string $class): void
{
    $validations = Yaml::parseFile($yamlFilePath));

    if (!is_array($validations) || !isset($validations[$class])) {
        return;
    }

    $constraints = [];
    $properties = $validations[$class]['properties'];
    foreach ($properties as $property => $propertyConstraints) {
        foreach ($propertyConstraints as $propertyConstraint) {
            $namespace = key($propertyConstraint);
            $constraints[$property][$namespace] = $propertyConstraint[$namespace];
        }
    }

    $constraintOptions = [];
    foreach ($constraints as $property => $propertyConstraint) {
        foreach ($propertyConstraint as $namespace => $options) {
            $constraintOptions[] = new $namespace($options);
        }
        $builder->add($property, null, ['constraints' => $constraintOptions]);
    }
}
```

Note: If you already created a field, instead of $builder->add you can use the code proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543394/4239022